# What are the drawbacks of moving an app to SD card?

Tags: applications, sd-card

Since I upgraded to Android 2.2, I noted some minor disadvantages of moving an app to SD card, like having to wait the SD card to be mounted after a reboot to be able launch the app.

What other disadvantages are there?