# How to run android phone flawlessly ?

Tags: performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are some general tips on improving overall performance of an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/what-are-some-general-tips-on-improving-overall-performance-of-an-android-phone)

I have been using android phone(Sony Xperia Tipo Dual) few months now .However I see that there are loads of things to learn as a new user .From rooting your device to effective memory management can seem quite intimidating .Also there are lot of good [blogs](http://www.bongizmo.com/blog/moving-all-android-apps-to-sdcard-apps2sd-froyo/) explaining how to use memory effectively .

So what are tips/tricks you would give to first time android user so that he can use the phone effectively so that there is no dips in performance ?

Answer based on all the available android versions .

Comment: Check out this post: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/what-are-some-general-tips-on-improving-overall-performance-of-an-android-phone

Answer (score 0):

Memory management: do not use any task killer, Android takes care of it well. Killing apps only waste battery when they have to be respawned.

Rooting the phone does help - you can weed out all the useless carrier and OEM bloat. Also, after using a bunch of droids over the past few years, I'd say modified, cleaner versions of stock ROMs >>> custom ROMs in terms of stability and battery life, with the sole exception being Nexus devices.

Learning to tweak and perfect Android is like doing it with Linux distros on PCs and servers - there is always more, it is a never ending process and we are all learning. There is no definitive list or article, really.

And most important, don't accept others' advice without thinking about or questioning it.