# How to optimize my Rooted desire bravo for gaming?

Tags: htc-desire, custom-roms, performance

Presently using the [Runnymede AIO V6.0.4.3 Special Edition [Stable]](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1315961URL)

Tried [Cyanogenmode-7.2 Stable](http://get.cm/get/jenkins/3075/cm-7.2.0.1-bravo.zip)

But I am finding great lag in performance when playing games. Such as Angry Gran, Temple run, Temple run 2.  Is there anything I can do to improve the performance?

Comment: Did you take a look at this? http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3986/what-are-some-general-tips-on-improving-overall-performance-of-an-android-phone

Comment: @w4rumy I read that, it does address some info. But I am looking something root improvements like overclocking and esp to improve its graphic acceleration..