# How to make rooted android phone faster and avoid battery drain

Tags: root-access, battery-life, performance, overclocking, setcpu

I have rooted by Samsung S dous s7562 (645 RAM single core 1ghz processor)phone using Kingo Android root desktop App.

I decided to root my phone as it was very slow .

I have already done the following to speed up the phone :

- Uninstalled unnecessary system apps.
- Frozen bloatware
- Using RAMBooster App
- Tried overclocking a bit using CPU Adjuster app

**Problem :**

> I don't have any idea regarding how much should I overclock based on
>   my device specification.
>
> I changed min CPU speed from 245Mhz to 320Mhz .
>
> But since I have overclocked it the battery is drain too fast although
>   the performance is a little better(but still lagging a bit).

**Please suggest what should I do to speed up my phone without damaging it and without battery drain(battery is weak already as its an 1.25 year old phone)**

Also please let me know How can I move apps to sdcard as even movetosd apps for rooted android devices are not working , (as my internal memory is read as sdcard)

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, Rachita! Have you checked our [performance tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/performance/info) for some clues? Also its [most frequented questions](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance?sort=frequent)? Gives you e.g. [What are some general tips on improving overall performance of an Android phone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3986/16575), [My device is getting slow, apps start misbehaving/crashing. What can I do?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/35367/16575), and more.

Answer (score 1):

[Crossbreeder](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2113150) is a great addition to any Android device. It does a lot of things, among them: DNS caching and paralleling, ad and spyware blocking, modulation of OS entropy levels. It helped A LOT  when I had an HTC One V [1.5GHz CPU (OC'd), 512 MB RAM, Android 4.2.2]. So much so that I also flashed it onto my Nexus 5.

[Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify) helps by allowing you to manage background processes and program it accordingly for best results.

Lastly, [Titanium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup) has the only "move to SD card" feature that I can vouch for. Give it a try and see if it can move the apps you need off your SD card. You should also note that this might the associated app's widgets unavailable (see [Issue 11283](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11283); opened in 2010 and marked as "WorkingAsIntended").