# android 2.2 - extending phone storage to SD

Tags: mount, app2sd

I heard there is a way to "mount" some of the SD card's space and use it to extend the phone's storage. I need this so I can have space to install apps that only allow to be installed on the phone.

Anyone heard about it?

I'm using `Android v2.2`, with an `HTC Desire`.

Comment: Didn't know we had one of those :)
How can I migrate it?

Comment: The question has been flagged and will be migrated by a moderator shortly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move any apps to sdcard if you are rooted. There are apps on the Market for it [Move2SD Enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.leinardi.setinstalllocation) and [App Swap](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.jrummy.froyo.apps2sd)

Better yet, if you are using custom ROMs (e.g. CyanogenMod), some of them have settings to allow you to migrate any apps. You might want to check those out first if you're using custom ROM.

If you want to do it manually (not recommended for pregnant man, or those currently having a heart attack), then you can use Terminal Emulator or ADB to run a few fairly standard set of Linux/Unix commands. The `mount` command can rebind any folder in your filesystem another location in the filesystem. Alternatively, you may also create symbolic links using the `ln` command. See the `mount` and `ln` manual for this.

Comment: Good answer.  I am wondering if he means using an Ext partition on the SD card, though.

Comment: @Matthew Read: What does `Ext partition` mean? I assume I do mean it, but just don't know it.

Comment: @RonK: ext partition is the de facto standard filesystem used in Linux (the equivalent in Windows is NTFS and used to be FAT, the equivalent in Macs is HFS+). It is basically a specification that specifies how files and folders are written on a storage medium. However, Windows can't read ext filesystem (at least not without extra software), that's why most manufacturer used FAT for external SD card, despite the fact that FAT is an inferior filesystem.

Comment: ext partition used to be necessary for app2sd since FAT partition does not have any security scheme, and Linux (in fact, most Unix systems) relies on filesystem permission to enforce security. ext, being developed specifically for Linux, has the advantage that its security scheme closely resembles the OS' security scheme.

Answer (score 2):

Android OS versions 2.2 and above have built-in functionality for moving apps to SD Card. Go to `Menu -> Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications -> SD Card`, then tap on any available app without a checkmark, and the button `Move to SD card` should be enabled.  This will move a major portion of the app to the SD Card and free up space for more apps.

If you are rooted and running a custom ROM that supports Ext2/3/4 partition types, there are special [scripts](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=715940) available that can "fool" your phone into thinking that a portion of your SD Card is actually part of the internal memory, thus allowing you to install tons of apps without most of the [disadvantages](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9767/other-than-portability-are-there-any-other-advantages-or-disadvantages-to-stor/9787#9787) of built-in method.  Be advised that this method is fairly complicated to install, and requires re-partitioning of the SD Card, flashing a hacky script, and can cause instability of the phone.