# What are the benefits of moving apps to the SD card?

Tags: app2sd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Other than portability, are there any other advantages (or disadvantages) to storing apps on external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9767/other-than-portability-are-there-any-other-advantages-or-disadvantages-to-stor)

I'm trying to decide if I should make the move.  I was hoping moving apps to the SD card would have them magically show up if the OS is wiped but from a little reading it looks like even apps on the SD card are unique to the OS they're installed on.  I'm not really seeing another good reason to move them.

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit (I think of) would be to save space on the internal memory of the device.

That is also the main reason I have my apps in the SD card with my old Treo (with palms there was this option too, depending on the launcher you used).