# How to move application to SD card in samsung galaxy s duos

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, app2sd, samsung-galaxy-s-duos

How to move application to SD card in samsung galaxy s duos.

I have tried some application from Google Play but did not succeed.

Plz help me

Answer (score 3):

According to our [tag wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/samsung-galaxy-s-duos/info), the Duos comes with Android 4.x -- which natively supports to move apps to SD:

*Settings→Apps→Manage Apps*, sroll to the app you want to move, tapp the "Move to SDCard" button.

If the button is grayed out, the app does not support being moved to SDCard. See [Unable to move few Apps to SD Card](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/27816/16575) for details on that.

Questions (and their answers) you might want to check for further details:

- [How to install APK files on SDCARD?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/3436/16575)
- [Other than portability, are there any other advantages (or disadvantages) to storing apps on external storage?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/9767/16575)
- [Can I force move to sd card applications that don't want to be moved there?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/16987/16575)

---

**EDIT:** Googling around revealed several technical reviews stating that app2sd is *not* working on the Duos. Only known working solutions include either rooting the device, or using the Android SDK, see e.g. [How to move almost all Android apps to SD card (no root required)](http://www.bongizmo.com/blog/moving-all-android-apps-to-sdcard-apps2sd-froyo/): here a comment reports to have successfully accomplished the task using a terminal emulator instead of the SDK. Putting things together, a How-To could basically look like this:

- install a terminal app from the playstore (e.g. [Android Terminal Emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm))
- start the app
- enter `pm set-install-location 2`, followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key (if that throws an error other than "permission denied", try `pm setInstallLocation 2` instead. In case of a "permission denied", you would need to root the device)

To my knowledge, this would only set the *default installation target* to the SDCard, but not move any apps itself. The howto there further describes one could *then* move apps manually. I have not tried this (I don't want to move things to SD), and so cannot confirm anything -- but it might be worth a try.

And again, the comments there are not all clear. While one claimed success, another user writes:

> I can confirm this procedure cannot be done for Samsung S Duos.
>   Even checked with Samsung Customer Care and they confirmed that Android 4.0x will not support movement of apps from the phone memory to External SD.

Same is, btw., claimed by LG support (something like "not our fault, blame Google"). But as other users say they can use app2sd fine on their 4.x devices, I cannot believe that it is ICS's fault, as the options are still shown fine even on my 4.1.x devices.

Comment: There is no button Move to SDCard in my Application manager

Comment: Is there no "Move..." button next to the "Delete data" in the "storage" section of the app details page? Just checking on my LG, I cannot find it either. Must be something done by the manufacturer/provider that it is removed from some devices, as ICS still should have it. In *Manage apps*, what tabs do you have there? // I just googled a little, and found that some manufacturers (like e.g. LG) intentionally disabled this functionality. Could very well be your SGS Duos is affected by this as well :(

Comment: Further checks in several tech reviews confirm that app2sd does not work on the Duos. Only known work-arounds include rooting the device. Similar issue to my LG Optimus 4X as well, by the way, as I found out on the way :(

Comment: I do know it was removed in Jellybean by Google (at least in 4.2, I can't remember if it was still there in 4.1). The goal is to push manufacturers to use one big solid partition so you can share your "sdcard" and application space. On devices that have separate partitions, it definitely can severely limit available space on the phone for apps.

Comment: That goes to be political, but IMHO this decision should be left to the user. Nevertheless, I still see the option on my 4.1.1 tablets. But as they also still use UMS (instead of the "favored" MTP), this might as well be a "speciality" of this one manufacturer... I just googled for "app2sd android 4.0", but an official statement from Google I didn't see in the result list.

Answer (score -1):

study the whole answer ***PATIENTLY***  and i am sure this will help

i will tell you how to swap your internal memory and external memory

ex. if you have a 8gb sd card, then your internal memory will be 8gb and the external will be 2gb

***YOU DO THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK AND I TAKE NO LIABILITY IF SOMETHING GOES WRONG***

HERE IS THE PROCEDURE

**for this your phone must be rooted**
download ***root external 2 internal*** app from play store.
allow the superuser request when you open the app.

go to settings

here

select **Default SGS3 roms**

select **send rescan**

select **use per default**

then go to ***the ext.sdcard device access***

there u will see  /dev/block/vold/179:49

change it **to /dev/block/vold/179.33**

go back on *clicking the enternal 2 internal* on the up left of the screen

select at boot (if not selected)

then click on ***external>internal***

then on ***at boot if init.d....*

TADA

THATS IT NOW GO TO SETTINGS AND SEE YOUR STORAGE

BUBYE

"THIS IS APPLICABLE ONLY FOR GALAXY S DUOS"

Comment: How does this answer the question and help the OP move an app to their SD card?