# How to have Android use one ext3fs partition instead of going rogue with virtual partitions for apps on the external sd card?

Tags: applications, rooting, external-sd, app2sd, partitions

As [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/9787/11710) pointed out, moving apps to your external sd card decreases your overall system performance due to the tens or hundreds of partitions created for those apps.  Now I wonder, is there any way to avoid this and have the system use a single partition, maybe formatted ext3 or xfs or the like? My devices are rooted, if that helps, but I'd prefer sticking to the stock (samsung galaxy) OS.

Comment: Playing on the tags you've used: have you checked our [app2sd tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/app2sd/info)? Keep your eyes open there for e.g. *Link2SD* and *Extended methods* :)

Comment: @Izzy good point, sounds like I should try [tag:link2sd]

Comment: And if that works out the way expected, make sure to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and share your solution :)