# Where can I find my Android applications?

Tags: installation

I want to know where do Android applications stay?

For example, if you install a program with package name `xx.yyy` ,  you will see `xx.yyy-1.apk` in `/data/app` and will see `xx.yyy` in /data/data and `data@app@xx@yyy-1apk@classes.dex` in `/data/dalvik-cache`.

I want to know other places that a program can stay.

At a glance, I want to remove a program manually, and I want to know places the application might occupy.

At the end I want to know the function of each file.  What's the duty of `data@app@xx@yyy-1apk@classes.dex`  in `/data/dalvik-cache` for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `/data/app-private` directory is another location of 3rd-party protected apps.  System apps that come pre-installed with the ROM are stored in a read-only `/system/app` directory.

`/data/dalvik-cache` contains optimized bytecode for each installed app, which allows the system to launch it faster.  These `...@classes.dex` files get generated at installation/update time, or during the first boot-up for pre-installed apps.

Also, with Android 2.2 Google introduced ability to move apps to the SD Card.  When you do this, a new virtual mount point is created under `/dev/block/dm-X` (where "X" is a sequential number starting with 1) which points to `/mnt/asec/xx.yy-1`.

`/data/data/` folder contains settings, preferences and cache for all apps, each within its own folder named after the package name.  E.g. `/data/data/xx.yyy/`.

Comment: Good answer.  I would only add: Apps can create any files / folders on the SD card they like, so there's nothing to do but inspect and remove those manually.